# How to change shipping cost based on cart subtotal?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing my own plugin to add a new shipping method for WooCommerce. What I want is to change the price of the shipping method based on the cart subtotal.

subtotal 0 - 39,99 = cost 2.50,
subtotal 40 - x = cost 0

So far I have this:

```
public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
    $rate = array(
        'id' => $this->get_rate_id(),
        'label' => $this->title,
        'cost' => $this->get_option( 'base_rate' ),
        'package' => $package
    );
    $this->add_rate( $rate );
}
```

and this

```
'base_rate' => array(
    'title'       => __( 'Base rate', 'woocommerce' ),
    'type'        => 'price',
    'description' => __( 'Base delivery rate' ),
    'default'     => '',
    'css'         => 'width: 100px;',
    'placeholder' => wc_format_localized_price( 0 )
),
```

But I have no idea how to set the conditions.

Comment: Doesn't Woocommerce come with this feature built-in?

Comment: No, it does not. You have to use the combination of flat rate and free shipping, so you have to add two shipping methods.

Comment: I really don't think that you need to build any custom shipping method for this… This just can be done in `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook. So you should better explain what you have and what you want to have in details (the rate Ids for each shipping zones … *and so on* …)